# aps-iot-extensions-demo---'Error: 401 ()'

Tags: iot, forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am new here.

I try to run locally with https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo

1.change to my clientID & secret
2.use *rac_basic_sample_project.rvt* sample project

[image: 1]

Please help me to check the problem.

Xhr.js:900          GET https://cdn.derivative.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YW0zcXo4NTV3M2JodHNqY3BrdzJlYWludHBzc25penktYmFzaWMtYXBwL3JhY19iYXNpY19zYW1wbGVfcHJvamVjdC5ydnQ?domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080 401

viewer.js:52 Uncaught (in promise) {code: 4, message: 'Error: 401 ()', errors: 401}

thanks.
Louis

1.change to my clientID & secret
2.use *rac_basic_sample_project.rvt* sample project

Comment: HTTP Status code 401 means that the access token passed to the viewer doesn't have access to the above URN. Could you try https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/ or just call [GET {urn}/manifest](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/manifest/urn-manifest-GET/) to check if you can get correct results (e.g. load the model or get manifest)?

Comment: I modify the model view guid and running successfully. thank you very much.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the good news

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is the incorrect model view GUID (saying `APS_MODEL_VIEW`) at https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo/blob/master/public/config.js#L2

After changing the URN, the `APS_MODEL_VIEW` must be changed together since the GUID specified in the [config.js](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo/blob/master/public/config.js#L2) is the master view's GUID. The master view is generated by Model Derivative service automatically, so its GUID is not persistent like other Revit views inside the RVT file.